# How to use jest configuration with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using nestjs.
Need run migrations before run all tests. And after all runned test nedd run clear test schema.
If i use javascript setup files in test/config/setup.js `package.json` all works.
But if i use typescript files dont work.

```
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfigFile": "tsconfig.json"
      }
    },
    "globalSetup": "./config/setup.ts",
    "globalTeardown": "./config/teardown.ts",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "./test",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

`test/config/setup.ts`

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'; // errors when run jest

module.exports = async () => {
    dotenv.config({path: '.env.test'});
};
```

Errors

```
/home/jashka/job/projects/project-name/test/config/setup.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my `jest.config.js` file, which works with `.ts` setup files. Add `'^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',` to transform your `.ts` files and change `tsConfigFile` to `tsConfig`.

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/tests/unit/setup.ts'],
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/tests/unit/globalSetup.ts',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/tests/unit/globalTeardown.ts',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/unit/**/(*.)spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babel: true,
      tsConfig: "tsconfig.json",
    }
  }
};
```